# use part of value of A1 to formula in cell B1

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

**EDIT:** In my cell A1 has string `value - 44` and I want to use 44 in a calculation `=44*2`.

How do I get the 44 from the end of cell A1?

Comment: Did you mean "my cell A1 contain string `value - 44` (or any other string with digits) and I want do some calculations with value of this digits as a number"? How about [**VALUE()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3150802) and [**REGEX()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id831542233029549)? Like as `=VALUE(REGEX(A1;"\d+"))*2`?

Comment: yes that's it. Thanks I have done it differently in Excel